# how to scan wifi clients (unconnectted) information in android hotspot mode?

Tags: android, wifi

I set the android wlan to hotspot mode with code, and I want to get surrounding android client infomation (with wifi open, but not connectted to my hotspot yet).
Is it possible to do this without root privilege?

Comment: You will not be able to get list of other wifi if you have created the hotspot

Comment: For that you need to do wifimanager.startScan() which will only work when wifi is enabled .And wifi and hotspot cannot work together